# Complexity Analysis of Structs and Enums

Tags: swift, data-structures, struct, enums

Does anyone know the complexity to initialize a struct or enum?

Or, do you know which of the 3 costs the least amount of time/resources to allocate memory for?

In my situation, I'm simply using a struct/enum to house variables for me to reference later. As an example, here's the equivalent struct/enum:

Using a struct:

```
struct Identifier {
    static let key = "a long string as a dictionary key, shortened using struct."
}
let dictionaryItem = aDictionary[Identifier.key]
```

Now using enums:

```
enum Identifier: String {
    case Key = "a long string as a dictionary key, shortened using enum."
}

let dictionaryItem = aDictionary[Identifier.Key.rawValue]
```

Which would be faster? Which is more effi

Comment: Do Not Optimize Prematurely.

Comment: I just googled your comment and I read about some of the implications of premature optimization. I will take your comment to heart but I'm still looking for an answer; Which of the 2 should I conform to?

Comment: "Which of the 2 should I conform to" Whichever you like. "Should" questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. It's your life, your app, your situation, your preferences. And there are no "faster" or "efficient" considerations in such a tiny blip of code.